# Cocos2d Mac ccDrawLine color

Tags: opengl, cocos2d-iphone

I am using cocos2d for mac. 
I have overloaded the ccdrawline of a CCLayer subclass inorder to draw a line. It works fine. To change the color to red I use
glColor4f(1.0f,0,0,1.0f);

but whatever value I gave to the glColor4f the color does not change. It remains white.
but I noticed that other openGL functions such as glLineWidth(5.0f) are working correctly!.

Comment: post some code! ccdrawline is not a method of CCLayer, as I understand it is a global function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on cocos2d 2.x you can use:

```
void ccDrawColor4F( GLfloat r, GLfloat g, GLfloat b, GLfloat a );
```

as defined in `CCDrawingPrimitives.h`.

Though as phix23 pointed out it's a global function, so you can use it straight away.